# QT Creator hangs on opening a file or project

Tags: qt, qt5

My previously installed QT SDK 1.2.1 was working fine.

Then, I tried to upgrade it to QT OpenSource 5.6.1. It was working fine.
One day, it started hanging on clicking "File--->Open a New File or Project".

I have reinstalled QT 5.6.1 multiple times, but it still hangs on that.
I tried the same for QT OpenSource 4.9.2 and 5.3.0, but they also show the same issue.

Have attached the screenshot on which QT hangs whenever I click on "Open a File or Project"

[image: 1]

Please help
Thanks

**UPDATE:** It also hangs on "File->Open File With ..."

Further, it shows no issue on "File->New Project"
However, when I choose, say, Widgets---->OK---->Browse for project folder location, it stucks there also.

So, basically anything related to opening my filesystem from QT causes hangs without even opening a new window for opening file/project

No other menu option click has any such issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried disabling the ***Welcome*** plugin (of ***QT Creator*** section) in ***Help--->About Plugins***

On disabling that, I am now able to do ***File->Open file/project***

:)

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete your "C:\Users\*Your.Profile*\AppData\Roaming\**QtProject**" folder

Comment: It still hangs on "File--->Open a New File or Project". Further, I discovered just now that "File->Open File With..." also leads to same situation. No other menu option click shows any issue

Comment: I wonder if I need to edit registry settings

Comment: Found only this [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-10733) but it's too old.
Try latest LTS [qt-5.12.9](http://master.qt.io/archive/qt/5.12/5.12.9/qt-opensource-windows-x86-5.12.9.exe) and when installing I did set system proxy to 0.0.0.0:123 so that it didn't ask for account and didn't try to connect to internet...
This works fine for me on Win10.1909.x64.

Comment: Tried all this, but couldn't resolve the issue. Thanks for you help